# Long-running stats process - thoughts on language choice?

Tags: java, php, python, statistics, long-running-processes

I am on a [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)) stack for a website I am managing. There is a need to roll up usage statistics (a variety of things related to our desktop product).

I initially tackled the problem with PHP (being that I had a bunch of classes to work with the data already). All worked well on my dev box which was using 5.3.

Long story short, 5.1 memory management seems to suck a lot worse, and I've had to do a lot of fooling to get the long-term roll up scripts to run in a fixed memory space. Our server guys are unwilling to upgrade PHP at this time. I've since moved my dev server back to 5.1 so I don't run into this problem again.

For mining of MySQL databases to roll up statistics for different periods and resolutions, potentially running a process that does this all the time in the future (as opposed to on a cron schedule), what language choice do you recommend? I was looking at Python (I know it more or less), Java (don't know it that well), or sticking it out with PHP (know it quite well).

---

**Edit: design clarification for commenter**

Resolutions: The way the rollup script works currently, is I have some classes for defining resolutions and buckets. I have year, month, week, day -- given a "bucket number" each class gives a start and end timestamp that defines the time range for that bucket -- this is based on arbitrary epoch date. The system maintains "complete" records, ie it will complete its rolled up dataset for each resolution since the last time it was run, currently.

SQL Strat: The base stats are located in many dissimilar schemas and tables. I do individual queries for each rolled up stat for the most part, then fill one record for insert. Your are suggesting nested subqueries such as:

INSERT into rolled_up_stats (someval, someval, someval, ... ) VALUES (SELECT SUM(somestat) from someschema, SELECT AVG(somestat2) from someschema2)

Those subqueries will generate temporary tables, right? My experience is that had been slow as molasses in the past. Is it a better approach?

**Edit 2: Adding some inline responses to the question**

Language was a bottleneck in the case of 5.1 php -- I was essentially told I made the wrong language choice (though the scripts worked fine on 5.3). You mention python, which I am checking out for this task. To be clear, what I am doing is providing a management tool for usage statistics of a desktop product (the logs are actually written by an EJB server to mysql tables). I do apache log file analysis, as well as more custom web reporting on the web side, but this project is separate. The approach I've taken so far is aggregate tables. I'm not sure what these message queue products could do for me, I'll take a look.

To go a bit further -- the data is being used to chart activity over time at the service and the customer level, to allow management to understand how the product is being used. You might select a time period (April 1 to April 10) and retrieve a graph of total minutes of usage of a certain feature at different granularities (hours, days, months etc) depending on the time period selected. Its essentially an after-the-fact analysis of usage. The need seems to be tending towards real-time, however (look at the last hour of usage)

Comment: 1. Why do you want it to be long-running? Why is periodic running through cron-job not enough?
2. I assumed that the roll-up scripts run an SQL like "INSERT INTO RolledUpTable SELECT SUM(something) FROM RawTable GROUPBY Element_id" or some such, yet you seem to imply that the roll-up scripts read the information into the process, process them, then push them into the DB. This sounds like a weird design choice.
Please clarify your question :)

Comment: Added clarifications... sort of spawns a separate question though ;-)

Comment: Also, it doesn't necessarily need to be long running. The reason I thought that might be an okay approach is because after using the system, the folks are already interested in near real time data at an hourly resolution. May be an unreasonable request, but assuming it is not, a cron job doesn't seem to cut the mustard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of different approaches to this problem, some of which are mentioned here, but what you're doing with the data post-rollup is unclear...?

If you want to utilize this data to provide digg-like 'X diggs' buttons on your site, or summary graphs or something like that which needs to be available on some kind of ongoing basis, you can actually utilize memcache for this, and have your code keep the cache key for the particular statistic up to date by incrementing it at the appropriate times.

You could also keep aggregation tables in the database, which can work well for more complex reporting. In this case, depending on how much data you have and what your needs are, you might be able to get away with having an hourly table, and then just creating views based on that base table to represent days, weeks, etc.

If you have tons and tons of data, and you need aggregate tables, you should look into offloading statistics collection (and perhaps the database queries themselves) to a queue like RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ. On the other side of the queue put a consumer daemon that just sits and runs all the time, updating things in the database (and perhaps the cache) as needed.

One thing you might also consider is your web server's logs. I've seen instances where I was able to get a somewhat large portion of the required statistics from the web server logs themselves after just minor tweaks to the log format rules in the config. You can roll the logs every , and then start processing them offline, recording the results in a reporting database.

I've done all of these things with Python (I released [loghetti](http://github.com/bkjones/loghetti) for dealing with Apache combined format logs, specifically), though I don't think language is a limiting factor or bottleneck here. Ruby, Perl, Java, Scala, or even awk (in some instances) would work.

Comment: Language was a bottleneck in the case of 5.1 php -- I was essentially told I made the wrong language choice (though the scripts worked fine on 5.3). You mention python, which I am checking out for this task. To be clear, what I am doing is providing a management tool for usage statistics of a desktop product (the logs are actually written by an EJB server to mysql tables). I do apache log file analysis, as well as more custom web reporting on the web side, but this project is separate. The approach I've taken so far is aggregate tables. I'm not sure what these MQ products do, I'll take a look.

Comment: To go a bit further -- the data is being used to chart activity over time at the service and the customer level, to allow management to understand how the product is being used. You might select a time period (April 1 to April 10) and retrieve a graph of total minutes of usage of a certain feature at different granularities (hours, days, months etc) depending on the time period selected. Its essentially an after-the-fact analysis of usage. The need seems to be tending towards real-time, however (look at the last hour of usage)

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on a project to do a similar thing in the past, so I have actual experience with performance. You would be hard pressed to beat the performance of "INSERT ... SELECT" (not "INSERT...VALUES (SELECT ...)". Please see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

The advantage is that if you do that, especially if you keep the roll-up code in MySQL procedures, is that all you need from the outside is just a cron-job to poke the DB into performing the right roll-ups at the right times -- as simple as a shell-script with '`mysql <correct DB arguments etc.> "CALL RollupProcedure"`'

This way, you are guaranteeing yourself zero memory allocation bugs, as well as having decent performance when the MySQL DB is on a separate machine (no moving of data across machine boundary...)

EDIT: Hourly resolution is fine -- just run an hourly cron-job...

Comment: Sorry to be a bit of a dork here, I am no SQL ninja. I can see the benefits of a the stored procedure. However, is there a solution for data spanning multiple tables? Or would you recommend a INSERT ... SELECT statement for each table we're interested in? Also, the time resolutions -- did you use rolling time periods on your project? IE, the last 24 hours, or the last week? I am trying to use fixed periods (Monday to Monday is a week, for instance). Users thought selecting Last Monday through Last Wednesday with a day resolution should give them exactly that. Seems hard with stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running mostly SQL commands, why not just use MySQL etc on the command line? You could create a simple table that lists aggregate data then run a command like `mysql -u[user] -p[pass] < commands.sql` to pass SQL in from a file.

Or, split the work into smaller chunks and run them sequentially (as PHP files if that's easiest).

If you really need it to be a continual long-running process then a programming language like python or java would be better, since you can create a loop and keep it running indefinitely. PHP is not suited for that kind of thing. It would be pretty easy to convert any PHP classes to Java.

Comment: See design clarification -- I added notes on the way the resolutions are calc'd to maintain some semblance of sanity as to what records match up to what time periods across all the calcs. Something like this feasible in raw sql queries... or perhaps is there a better way to manage the resolutions?